# Add date and text fields in formula?

Tags: formula

I'm having a text field say text = 20 and a datefield say date=12/04/2012(here date is always system.today's date). now I want to add both the fields and the result should be 12/24/2012.... How would I get it by using formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose a formula field, choose a Date and then try the below formula

TODAY() + VALUE(Text_FIeld__c)